# How do I install software from a CD or DVD shared from a Windows 7 PC?

Tags: macos, sharing, dvd, optical-drive

I have a MacBook Air and I'd like to install CD- and DVD-based software on it without having to purchase an external CD/DVD drive.

I stumbled upon the CD & DVD sharing feature OS X supports but I've been having trouble getting it to work. I'm sharing my DVD and CD based software using a Windows 7-based PC with drive sharing enabled. But when I try to access the drive the Mac "thinks a lot" and then it says (roughly translated from danish):

> Action could not be completed, because the original subject to "Warcraft III" doesn't exist

I've tried this with multiple software discs, all have similar error message results when I try to access the shared disc from my MacBook Air.

How can I make drive sharing work from my Windows PC to my MacBook Air so that I can install this software?

Additional information:

- MacBook Air is running OS X Lion
- Practically no HDD-space used on the MacBook Air
- The PC with the CD/DVD drive is running Windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you copy the CD to a disk image on the PC, you can put the image on a USB stick and transfer it to your Air. I am not sure how to do this on Window, but I'm sure you can find out how to do this somewhere.

[WinImage](http://www.winimage.com/winimage.htm) looks like it should do what you want.

Also look at [this article on creating CD images on Windows.](http://abdussamad.com/archives/81-How-to-create-and-mount-a-CD-image-in-windows.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you know how to mount images in OS X Lion`:)

Comment: Double click and it should automatically mount it. I use SL, so maybe Lion is different. Let me know if you can get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Disc share does not work for game discs.  So unfortunately you'll have to find another way, maybe with usb.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5287?viewlocale=en_US